# Error when executing an interpreter file

Tags: c, exec, executable, interpreter

I tried to execute a program through the interpreter file. I used the fork() and execl() function in C. Here is my code:

```
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
        printf("fork error");
    else if (pid == 0) {     /* child */
        if (execl( "/home/alien/testinterp",         /* the interpreter file */
                   "testinterp", "arg1", (char *)0) < 0)
            printf("execl error");
```

In the file "/home/alien/testinterp", there is:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

I can run /bin/sh in the shell. I edited the interpreter file using Emacs.

When I run my program, I encount the error.("execl error").

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does `/home/alien/testinterp` executable? if not, please `chmod +x /home/alien/testinterp`

Comment: Using gdb? Sorry I'm a beginner.

Comment: When checking errors from system calls, always print out at least [`errno`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/errno) as well, or if you want a readable message either use [`perror`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/perror) or [`strerror`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By help of the comments of the question post, the **answer** is:

`/home/alien/testinterp` is not executable, so adding executable bit to this file will fix the problem: `chmod +x /home/alien/testinterp`

**PS1**: how did I guess?

> I edited the interpreter file using Emacs

I guessed that this file was probably newly created without executable bit.

**PS2**: guessing can't really fix problem, what is better way?

1. Print the `errno`, `perror()` is useful.
2. This error is come from `exec*()`, you can try to execute it directly via the shell to show what will happen

   $ /home/alien/testinterp arg1
3. Some functions like `exec*()`, `fork()` are wrapper of syscall, you can use `strace` to show the information while the syscalls is invoked.

   strace -ff path_to_your_program